# overlapping sequences in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

given a list of strings how can i find overlapping sequences

```
arr=['iloveapple','banana','ilove','ban']
substring_list=[]
for idx,s in enumerate(arr):
    if idx==0:
        substring_list.append(s)
    else:
        if any(s in x for x in substring_list):
            continue
        else:
            substring_list.append(s)


print(substring_list)
```

This method is very slow when the list grows large (>1000) . Is there a better way to handle this. Or is there a better data structure to store this overlapping sequences

Comment: You have to clearly define what "overlapping" means here

Comment: `ilove` is overlapping in `iloveapple` and `ilove` .`ban` is overlapping with `banana`

Comment: But using your code I get `['iloveapple', 'ilovebanana']` as a result. So this is not your expected output? Ah okay you changed the example

Comment: @user8408080 yes this is the expected result. But I am looking for  a better way because here the complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: @user8408080 Apparently the OP intends the output to remove the overlapping sequences from the input.

Comment: So every entry, which is completely contained in another entry should be eliminated? Is that correct? For example: `["abc", "ab", "b"] -> ["abc"]`

Comment: @user8408080 yes

Comment: [Ternary search tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-search-tree/)

Comment: @MichaelButscher can you explain how it can be done using Ternary search tree

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ternary search tree is useful only for prefix searches, not substring searches, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, forget it, it doesn't work (as @blhsing mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

You can add all possible substrings of a given string in `arr` to a `seen` set, so that you can look up whether or not a new word in `arr` is a substring of any previous strings with *O(1)* time complexity:

```
seen = set()
substring_list = []
for s in arr:
    if s not in seen:
        substring_list.append(s)
    seen.update({s[i:i + n + 1] for n in range(len(s)) for i in range(len(s) - n)})
```

`substring_list` becomes:

```
['iloveapple', 'ilovebanana']
```

Comment: so is the complexity better than O(n^2) ?

Comment: Yes, the complexity of this approach is *O(n * m ^ 2)*, where `n` is the length of the list and `m` is the average length of the words in the list, but since the lengths of words are usually much smaller and than the lengths of the input lists, and since the average length of words are usually stable, `m` can actually be seen as a constant, so when `n` is large this solution is effectively *O(n)*.

Comment: You're welcome to benchmark this solution against yours with your 1000+ word list, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a list comprehension and skip the whole list building part.

```
#make sure to sort the list first
arr = sorted(arr, key = len)
print([s for i, s in enumerate(arr) if all(s not in _ for _ in arr[i + 1:])])
#['iloveapple', 'ilovebanana']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you need suffix trees. They are the most efficient string matching data-structures. You can build on this to figure out which string in the list overlaps with others.

```
from suffix_trees import STree

arr=['iloveapple','banana','ilove','ban']

suffix_arr = "".join(arr)

st = STree.STree(suffix_arr)

for i, s in enumerate(arr):
    overlapped_index = st.find_all(s)
    for index in overlapped_index:
        print(arr[i], " overlaps ", index,  suffix_arr[index:] )
```

Comment: No need for the comprehension in the join method. It's redundant

Answer (score 0):

You could try to let string functions work for you:

```
  arr=['iloveapple','banana','ilove','ban']
  allStrings = " ".join(arr)
  substring_list = [ s for s in arr if len(allStrings.split(s))>2 ]
```

Joining all the strings together (with a separator) will give you a single pool of text to search into.  Knowing that each string is present at least one, splitting the combined strings on any of the keyword should give only two parts if there is only one instance.  But if there is an overlap, then the smaller keyword will appear more than once and cause additional splits.