# Finding only superstrings in collection

Tags: python, numpy

While trying to help answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54964548/225020) question I figured numpy would be a great alternative to python loops, although I can't seem to figure out how to do it and it's now become a mind puzzle I want to figure out but can't. I don't want to be credited with asking the same question but I do think that numpy may be better here.

The issue at hand:

Given a massive list of strings

```
data = ['test', 'foo','testing','foobar', 'bar', 'pie', 'applepie', ...]
```

Return a list with only the strings that contain substrings from the strings within the given list:

```
['testing', 'foobar', 'applepie']
```

I've tried the following: <sub>after several other failed attempts but this seems to make the most sense to me</sub>

```
import numpy as np

data = ['test', 'foo','testing','foobar', 'bar', 'pie', 'applepie']

d = np.unique(np.array(data))
print(d[((d in d) & (not d == d))])
```

Obviously this returns an empty array, but I cannot seem to figure out the correct filter. I've seen other similair questions/answers but to my dismay no answers use numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think numpy is a good way to do this, why not a list comprehension like:

```
print([i for i in data if any([x in i and x!=i for x in data])])
```

Output:

```
['testing', 'foobar', 'applepie']
```

I think that's very good already, you answered it right, but also you can write a loop:

```
l = []
for i in data:
    if any([x in i and x!=i for x in data]):
        l.append(i)
print(l)
```

Comment: That's my answer to his question just with different naming

Comment: Also do you ever sleep? Every time I'm on you are too! haha\